# is there a better datetime html5 polyfill which behaves well with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, datetime, polyfills

The html specs are a bit inconsistent about datetime fields:

- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#date-and-time-state-(type=datetime)
- http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/forms.html#date-state-(type=date)

even so, it's almost expected that such problem to emerge time to time.

Looking for implementations, i've found a few:

- https://github.com/chemerisuk/better-dateinput-polyfill
- https://github.com/chemerisuk/better-timeinput-polyfill

But to solve my problem using angular i needed to bind the same attr model on two inputs, and it's bad, since two fields, each one with your own clear button will erase both inputs. Also it is defective on firefox. (*please see plunker*):

```
`angular.module("foo",[]).controller("fuzz",function($scope){
    $scope.bar=new Date();
    $scope.buzz=function(){ alert($scope.bar); };
});`
```

- http://plnkr.co/edit/UAU30vaRwst83jZDL5Nx?p=preview

Is there a better way? will i need to use two fields? does datetime works on mobile?

Any guidance is quite welcome.

Comment: Please clarify `it's seems bad, very bad`, I'm trying to understand what you are expecting the plunker example to do?

Comment: Where is the inconsistency that you have an issue with?

Comment: i'll remove this question, the alternatives are worse than the unwanted behavior.

i consider bad, very bad the intuitive clean button on such kind of date and time field, it erases both fields, since they are linked via ng-model.

a single field is preferred, but seems a no-go in this time

Comment: got it working on chrome, but on firefox the fields are blank text inputs, which leads me to the defective polyfills... the question therefore remains for a while.